# SVG Fill Path Animation

Tags: javascript, svg

I don't have experience with svg and animations, I have the following file [jsfiddle](https://goo.gl/H4bQVB) which i want to animate the fill path color.

I want to use it as a loader so the new colour should fill the path like Sliding across or something similiar that gives it a look of "loading". You can use any color it's just an example...

Thank you

Comment: Animate how? Fade-in to a colour? Slide across? Triggered by hover? So many questions!

Comment: @user3704796 Slide across :)
I want it to use it as a loader...

Comment: Ok - well, to achieve what you want, I would recommend turning your SVG on it's head. I.e. there should be a background colour (like the grey you used) which is solid, but the black lines should be transparent (like they have been cut out of they grey box) that way, you could just have a coloured block stretch from left to right behind it, and it will achieve the look you want.

To be honest, you could just do away with the SVG and use a PNG for the cut out image. It'll work on older browsers that way too!

Comment: @MatthewLymer
I cannot use png because the colors of the line should change from one color to another...As i said i don't have experience with SVG, can you please post a jsfiddle how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: As I said, the line colour of the line doesn't need to change! :) The background colours just do, and the png would be a simple overlay. I think achieving what you want with a SVG would be too complex compared to a VERY simple implementation with a PNG and a bit of CSS. Particularly if you're not very experienced with SVGs.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I know it's not fully the way you want to do it, but view this link:

http://cdn.tinfishcreativedev.eu/eyeLoad/

It has a VERY simple implementation (quite crude at the minute, but just to get you started).

The code in the HTML file is as follows:

```
<style>
body{
    background:#F3F5F6;
    text-align: center;
}

.loader{
    background: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height:63px;
    width:100px;
    margin-top:300px;
}


.loader img{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:2;
}

.loaderBar{
    background: #16C38B;
    width: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-animation:grow 2s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes grow{
    0%{ width:0; }
    100%{ width: 100%; }
}
</style>
<div class="loader">
    <img src="eye.png" width="100" />
    <div class="loaderBar">
</div>
```

You could even do it with JS instead of keyframes to get it working on the older browsers like IE8 if needed.

Comment: No problem - just a heads up that I will be removing that from my CDN in the next day or so - so if you need the files as an example, best download them ASAP :)